# TypeError: destroy is not a function in useEffect caused by async/await

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My React Native `(0.61.5)` has a `16.9.0` React bundled which is not the most current one. In app `useEffect` returns an error of `TypeError: distroy is not a function`:

[image]

Here is the `useEffect` code:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/events/active?group_id=${encodeURIComponent(group_id)}&_role=${role}&_grpmember_id=${grpmember_id}&_group_id=${encodeURIComponent(group_id)}&_device_id=${encodeURIComponent(device_id)}`;
      let res =  await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
          headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
          "x-auth-token": token.password,
          "x-auth-secret": token.username,
        }
      });
      //check secret token 
      let secret = res.headers.get("x-auth-secret");
      let jwttoken = res.headers.get("x-auth-token");
      res = await res.json();
      if (secret && jwttoken && (typeof secret !== 'undefined') && (typeof jwttoken !== 'undefined') && secret !== null && jwttoken !== null) {
        if(await helper.updateJwtToken(secret, jwttoken)) {
          setToken({password: jwttoken, username: secret});
          authVal.updateToken(token); //set state token in App.js
        };
      } else if (jwttoken === "route to verfi") {
        navigation.navigate("Verif1", {cell: res.cell, cell_country_code: res.cell_country_code, existing_user:true});      
      };
      //update state
      var ordered_data = eventsByDate(res);
      setActiveEvents(ordered_data);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error in event refreshing data ", err);     
    };
  })
```

According to a [online post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/a0u38o/you_can_now_use_the_useeffect_hook_with_the_async/), the problem is most likely caused by a couple of `async/await` in the method. It seems to me that the more recent version of `React` shall fix this problem. What is the version of react shall I upgrade to? Or there is other work around for this instead of version upgrade.

Comment: the useEffect callback should return not a promise (not be async) see how its written correctly here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326#issuecomment-441680293

Answer (score 5):

I think you should remove the async keyword and just write `useEffect(() => {...});` The best way would be to create a separate function and use it:

```
const doStuff = async () => {...};
useEffect(() => { doStuff(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move your method inside another function and call that function inside useEffect.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    checkUserVerification();
 }, []);
 const checkUserVerification = async () => {
     await yourCode
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As per react documentation , useEffect is a synchronous method. So if you want to call an async method in useEffect state hook, please do something along the following lines:

```
useEffect(() => {
async function authenticateUser() {
  const response = await getRedirectResult(auth);
}
authenticateUser();
```

}, []);

Let me know if this will help!